# Passing another parameter into Kendo UI DropDownList change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am building my kendo ui dropdownlist components dynamically so I have a loop that builds for every element that is a dropdownlist.  Kendo UI appends more html to make it look like a dropdownlist but never updates the initial input fields value.  My plan is to do this on change so I can search for all the changes I made and get the values dynamically.  The problem is that when I pass in the specific item to the change event, it still tells me it is undefined.  Here is a snippet of the code:

```
for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
    var item = data[x];
    if($('#item-'+item.Name).length){
        $('#item-'+item.Name).kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: item.dataSource,
            dataTextField: "Label",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            value: (item.defaultValue != null) ? item.defaultValue : "",
            change: function(e, item){
                $('#item-'+item.Name).val(this.dataItem(e.item).Value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

on the change event the passed in "item" is always undefined.  I'm not sure why and how to solve it.  Can anyone help please, thank you in advance.

Comment: I found the answer, seems you cannot pass extra parameters to event functions in kendo ui.  What you have to do is:

    this.element.pro('id')

This will return the input field ID and you can set the value as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply use item without passing it? Assuming the item you want is "var item = data[x];" is declared outside the kendoDropDownList and you can use inside the change function.

```
for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
    var item = data[x];
    if($('#item-'+item.Name).length){
        $('#item-'+item.Name).kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: item.dataSource,
            dataTextField: "Label",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            value: (item.defaultValue != null) ? item.defaultValue : "",
            change: function(e){
                $('#item-'+item.Name).val(this.dataItem(e.item).Value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```